# Appium + WDIO + CircleCI unable to connect to Android device diring test

Tags: android, appium, circleci

During my try to integrate Appium + WDIO + CircleCI in order to execute tests on Android mobile simulator I am getting following error:
"Request failed with status 500 due to An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not find a connected Android device" although Android simulator is started and running and all prerequisites are installed during steps in CircleCI workflow

When I try to run tests locally from my mac everything works like a charm and tests are executed successfully

Attaching config WDIO config
config: {"runner":"local","specs":["./e2e_appium_mobile/specs/android/*.spec.js"],"capabilities":[{"platformName":"Android","maxInstances":1,"appium:deviceName":"Pixel_Sim_30","appium:orientation":"PORTRAIT","appium:automationName":"UiAutomator2","appium:app":"/Users/distiller/project/apps/connect-app.apk","appium:noReset":true,"appium:newCommandTimeout":240,"appium:autoGrantPermissions":true,"appium:autoAcceptAlerts":true}],"logLevel":"info","bail":0,"waitforTimeout":60000,"connectionRetryTimeout":150000,"connectionRetryCount":3,"services":[["appium",{"command":"appium","args":{"address":"localhost","port":4723}}]],"framework":"jasmine","jasmineNodeOpts":{"defaultTimeoutInterval":900000},"reporters":["spec"],"path":"/","host":"localhost","port":4723}

Attaching used CircleCI flow:
e2e_tests_appStore_android: &e2e_tests_appStore_android
macos:
xcode: '14.2.0'
resource_class: macos.x86.medium.gen2
parallelism: 1
steps:
- run:
name: Check java
command: java --version

```
- run:
    name: Check java location
    command: which java

- run:
    name: Install java8
    command: |
      HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1 brew tap homebrew/cask-versions
      HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1 brew install homebrew/cask-versions/adoptopenjdk8

- run:
    name: Check java after jre 8 installation
    command: java --version

- run:
    name: Print all installed java
    command: /usr/libexec/java_home -V

- run:
    name: Setup environment variables
    command: |
      echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/opt/node@14/bin:${HOME}/.npm/bin:${HOME}/${CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME}/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/share/android-sdk/tools/bin"' >> $BASH_ENV
      echo 'export ANDROID_HOME="/usr/local/share/android-sdk"' >> $BASH_ENV
      echo 'export ANDROID_SDK_HOME="/usr/local/share/android-sdk"' >> $BASH_ENV
      echo 'export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="/usr/local/share/android-sdk"' >> $BASH_ENV
      echo 'export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home' >> $BASH_ENV
      source $BASH_ENV

- run:
    name: Check java location 2
    command: which java

- run:
    name: Install Android sdk
    command: brew install android-sdk

- run:
    name: Install Android package
    command: (yes | sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-30" "extras;intel;Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager" "build-tools;30.0.2" "system-images;android-30;google_apis;x86" "emulator" --verbose) || true

- run:
    name: Accept licenses
    command: yes | sdkmanager --licenses || true

- run:
    name: Print sdkmanager packages
    command: sdkmanager --list --verbose

- run:
    name: Install Appium
    command: npm install -g appium

- run:
    name: Install appium doctor
    command: npm install -g appium-doctor

- run:
    name: Run appium-doctor on android
    command: appium-doctor --android

- run:
    name: Check emulator
    command: |
      ls -la ${HOME}
      ls -la ${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}/tools | grep "emulator"
      ls -la ${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}/emulator | grep "emulator"
      echo "ANDROID_SDK_ROOT test"
      ls -la ${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}
      echo "ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/emulator test"
      ls -la ${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}/emulator
      echo "ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools test"
      ls -la ${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}/platform-tools
      which emulator

- run:
    name: Create Android Emulator
    command: avdmanager create avd --force -n Pixel_Sim_30 -k "system-images;android-30;google_apis;x86" -g google_apis -d 19

- run:
    name: Install automation webdrivers
    command: |
      appium -v
      appium driver install uiautomator2
      appium driver install xcuitest

- run:
    name: Check installed drivers
    command: appium driver list --installed

- run:
    name: Check available avds and emulators
    command: |
      ${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}/emulator/emulator -list-avds
      avdmanager list avd

- checkout

- *restore_node_cache
- *install_packages_yarn
- *save_node_cache
- *install_expo
- *login_to_expo

# - run:
#     name: Start Android Emulator (background)
#     background: true
#     command: |
#       ${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}/emulator/emulator @Pixel_Sim_30 -version
#       # ${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}/emulator/emulator @Pixel_Sim_30 -gpu auto -no-accel -memory 4096 -no-audio -netdelay none -netspeed full
#       # ${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}/emulator/emulator -avd Pixel_Sim_30 -no-snapshot -gpu auto -no-accel -memory 4096 -no-audio -netdelay none -netspeed full > /dev/null 2>&1 &

- run:
    name: Wait for emulator
    no_output_timeout: 5m
    command: |
      ${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}/emulator/emulator @Pixel_Sim_30 -version
      ${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}/emulator/emulator -avd Pixel_Sim_30 -no-snapshot -gpu auto -no-accel -memory 4096 -no-audio -netdelay none -netspeed full > /dev/null 2>&1 &
      echo "Waiting for AVD to finish booting"
      ${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}/platform-tools/adb wait-for-device shell 'while [[ -z $(getprop getprop sys.boot_completed) ]]; do sleep 1; done;'
      echo "Android Virtual Device is now ready."
      /usr/local/share/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb devices

# - run:
#     name: Download app
#     command: |
#       npm i eas-cli@3.15.0 -g 
#       npx eas-cli build:list --platform=ios --limit=1 --json --non-interactive  --buildProfile=e2e-simulator
#       ./downloadAppiOS.sh Android

- run:
    name: Run appium
    command: appium
    background: true

- run:
    name: Run test on android emulator using appium and wdio
    command: |
      set -e
      npm run wdio:appium:android -- --AVD_NAME=Pixel_Sim_30 --artifacts-location /tmp/detox_artifacts --take-screenshots failing

# - *slack_notify
- *final_store_artifacts
- *save_test_results
```